# Image not saving with id name

Tags: php, html, database, save

Hey guys so I've made a system through which any picture upload from admin panel gets saved in a specific folder, according to the id!
But when I made some changes, My php website is not saving the picture with the id name and also its not storing more than 1 picture.

```
<?php 
// This file is www.developphp.com curriculum material
// Written by Adam Khoury January 01, 2011
// http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=442E340A42191003

// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "connect.php"; 

?>
<?php 
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
?>
<?php 
// Delete Item Question to Admin, and Delete Product if they choose
if (isset($_GET['deleteid'])) {
  echo 'Do you really want to delete product with ID of ' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '? <a href="inventory_list.php?yesdelete=' . $_GET['deleteid'] . '">Yes</a> | <a href="inventory_list.php">No</a>';
  exit();
}
if (isset($_GET['yesdelete'])) {
  // remove item from system and delete its picture
  // delete from database
  $id_to_delete = $_GET['yesdelete'];
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM products WHERE id='$id_to_delete' LIMIT 1") or die (mysql_error());
  // unlink the image from server
  // Remove The Pic -------------------------------------------
    $pictodelete = ("../inventory_images/$id_to_delete.jpg");
    if (file_exists($pictodelete)) {
              unlink($pictodelete);
    }
  header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// Parse the form data and add inventory item to the system
if (isset($_POST['product_name'])) {

    $product_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['product_name']);
  $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['price']);
  $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['category']);
  $subcategory = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['subcategory']);
  $details = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
  // See if that product name is an identical match to another product in the system
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT id FROM products WHERE product_name='$product_name' LIMIT 1");
  $productMatch = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
    if ($productMatch > 0) {
    echo 'Sorry you tried to place a duplicate "Product Name" into the system, <a href="inventory_list.php">click here</a>';
    exit();
  }
  // Add this product into the database now
  $sql = mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO products (product_name, price, details, category, subcategory, date_added) 
        VALUES('$product_name','$price','$details','$category','$subcategory',now())") or die (mysql_error());
     $pid = mysql_insert_id();
  // Place image in the folder 
  $newname = "$pid.jpg";
  move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], "../inventory_images/$newname");
  header("location: inventory_list.php"); 
    exit();
}
?>
<?php 
// This block grabs the whole list for viewing
$product_list = "";
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY date_added DESC");
$productCount = mysql_num_rows($sql); // count the output amount
if ($productCount > 0) {
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
             $id = $row["id"];
       $product_name = $row["product_name"];
       $price = $row["price"];
       $date_added = strftime("%b %d, %Y", strtotime($row["date_added"]));
       $product_list .= "Product ID: $id - <strong>$product_name</strong> - $$price - <em>Added $date_added</em> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href='inventory_edit.php?pid=$id'>edit</a> &bull; <a href='inventory_list.php?deleteid=$id'>delete</a><br />";
    }
} else {
  $product_list = "You have no products listed in your store yet";
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Inventory List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div align="center" id="mainWrapper">
  <?php include_once("../template_header.php");?>
  <div id="pageContent"><br />
    <div align="right" style="margin-right:32px;"><a href="inventory_list.php#inventoryForm">+ Add New Inventory Item</a></div>
<div align="left" style="margin-left:24px;">
      <h2>Inventory list</h2>
      <?php echo $product_list; ?>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <a name="inventoryForm" id="inventoryForm"></a>
    <h3>
    &darr; Add New Inventory Item Form &darr;
    </h3>
    <form action="inventory_list.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" id="myform" method="post">
    <table width="90%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6">
      <tr>
        <td width="20%" align="right">Product Name</td>
        <td width="80%"><label>
          <input name="product_name" type="text" id="product_name" size="64" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Product Price</td>
        <td><label>
          $
          <input name="price" type="text" id="price" size="12" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Category</td>
        <td><label>
          <select name="category" id="category">
          <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
          </select>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Subcategory</td>
        <td><select name="subcategory" id="subcategory">
        <option value=""></option>
          <option value="Hats">Hats</option>
          <option value="Pants">Pants</option>
          <option value="Shirts">Shirts</option>
          </select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Product Details</td>
        <td><label>
          <textarea name="details" id="details" cols="64" rows="5"></textarea>
        </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="right">Product Image</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="file" name="fileField" id="fileField" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>      
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><label>
          <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Add This Item Now" />
        </label></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    <br />
  <br />
  </div>
  <?php include_once("../template_footer.php");?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked the web server error logs?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\wamp\www\newest\admin\inventory_list.php on line 40 @Difster

Comment: Also, consider switching to PDO.

Answer (score 1):

You can't switch between `mysqli` and `mysql` using the same connection. (note `mysql_insert_id`).

Change `mysql_insert_id` to `mysqli_insert_id($conn)`.

Also: change all `mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST...)` to `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST...)` (... = POST name) and change `mysql_num_rows` to `mysqli_num_rows($conn, $sql)`.

Check the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) website for an overview of changes between `mysql` and `mysqli`.